# Saving culture dates Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a view which asks for a date to be selected. This is then saved to a database by creating an object and using linq to insert:

```
Event e = new Event();
e.Date = model.DateEntered;

context.Events.InsertOnSubmit(e);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

On this line I get an exception on the date format. Locally this is not the case as I understand it is to do with a globalization property needed in the web config file. My question is, is there a way to display the date to the user in the view in their expected format for their region and then save as a UK date format?

Where do I declare this globalization property and will it mean that US people will not be able to save?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it back to UTC when you save it to the database, by doing:

```
e.Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(model.DateEntered);
```

Comment: +1 Just to add to this answer, generally best practice is to always store your dates as UTC in the database and then convert them to the user's locale for display purposes.  It helps keep everything standardized and in proper chronological order regardless of where in the world the data originated.

Comment: How do you detect their locale any display accordingly?

Comment: @CR41G14 How are you displaying the date at the moment? Can you post your view?